# state_replicaset/state_replicaset.go98 error making http request: Get kube-state-metrics:8080/metrics: lookup kube-state-metrics on IP:53 no such host

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, metricbeat, typhoon-kubernetes

We are trying to start [metricbeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-reference-yml.html) on typhoon kubernetes cluster. But after startup its not able to get some pod specific events like restart etc because of the following

#### Corresponding metricbeat.yaml snippet

```yaml
# State metrics from kube-state-metrics service:
    - module: kubernetes
      enabled: true
      metricsets:
        - state_node
        - state_deployment
        - state_replicaset
        - state_statefulset
        - state_pod
        - state_container
        - state_cronjob
        - state_resourcequota
        - state_service
        - state_persistentvolume
        - state_persistentvolumeclaim
        - state_storageclass
        # Uncomment this to get k8s events:
        #- event  period: 10s
      hosts: ["kube-state-metrics:8080"]
```

#### Error which we are facing

```sh
2020-07-01T10:31:02.486Z        ERROR   [kubernetes.state_statefulset]  state_statefulset/state_statefulset.go:97       error making http request: Get http://kube-state-metrics:8080/metrics: lookup kube-state-metrics on *.*.*.*:53: no such host
2020-07-01T10:31:02.611Z        WARN    [transport]     transport/tcp.go:52     DNS lookup failure "kube-state-metrics": lookup kube-state-metrics on *.*.*.*:53: no such host
2020-07-01T10:31:02.611Z        INFO    module/wrapper.go:259   Error fetching data for metricset kubernetes.state_node: error doing HTTP request to fetch 'state_node' Metricset data: error making http request: Get http://kube-state-metrics:8080/metrics: lookup kube-state-metrics on *.*.*.*:53: no such host
2020-07-01T10:31:03.313Z        ERROR   process_summary/process_summary.go:102  Unknown or unexpected state <P> for process with pid 19
2020-07-01T10:31:03.313Z        ERROR   process_summary/process_summary.go:102  Unknown or unexpected state <P> for process with pid 20
```

I can add some other info which is required for this.

Comment: Please use typhoon-kubernetes not typhoon tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the Kube-State-Metrics deployed in your cluster in the kube-system namespace to make this work. Metricbeat will not come with this by default.

Please refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/running-on-kubernetes.html) for detailed deployment instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If your `kube-state-metrics` is deployed to another namespace, Kubernetes cannot resolve the name. E.g. we have `kube-state-metrics` deployed to the `monitoring` namespace:

```
$ kubectl get pods -A | grep kube-state-metrics
monitoring             kube-state-metrics-765c7c7f95-v7mmp                             3/3     Running   17         10d
```

You could set `hosts` option to the full name, including namespace, like this:

```
    - module: kubernetes
      enabled: true
      metricsets:
        - state_node
        - state_deployment
        - state_replicaset
        - state_statefulset
        - state_pod
        - state_container
        - state_cronjob
        - state_resourcequota
        - state_service
        - state_persistentvolume
        - state_persistentvolumeclaim
        - state_storageclass
      hosts: ["kube-state-metrics.<your_namespace>:8080"]
```